Horror movie with adopted kid
can someone please help me out trying to find the title of a horror movie. It's been quite a while since I've seen it and I can only remember some parts. Basically the movie was about a family with a couple of kids adopting another young child which starts killing the whole family.
In one of the scenes the adopted boy throws a tape recorder or some other music player in the whirl pool to kill his sister's boyfriend. I think he was somehow jealous of him. If I can recall correctly, in the end the boy kills the whole family and is found at a street being picked up and given to a new foster house implying the story to begin all over. A very disturbing movie. But having just watched Pet Cemetery I guess it cannot become much worse.

I think you're looking for Mikey (1992).

Mikey then falls in love with his new best friend, Ben's, older sister, Jessie. She, however, is not interested in him as she is 15 years older than Mikey and is dating a young man named David. In an attempt to make Jessie love him, he electrocutes David while he is in a Jacuzzi.
[...] At the end of the film, Mikey goes under the name "Josh" and is adopted by another family.


This is exactly it! Thank you very much.
